# why I can't change the transparency of a Drawable?

Tags: android, graphics

I want to get the background `Drawable` of a `View`, change it's transparency, and then set this new drawable as background of another `View`. what I do:

```
Drawable d=view.getBackgroung();
d.setAlpha(100);
secondView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

but the transparency doesn't change. what's wrong?

Comment: Try this setBackgroundColor(0x00000000)

Comment: then what to put instead of `0x00000000` ?

Answer (score 0):

@soheil create a bitmap with some transparency u want,then add that bitmap as background,

like this:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
bd.setAlpha(50);

ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
v.setImageDrawable(bd);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try d.setAlpha(0);
secondView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Answer (score -1):

in xml layout try this.

android:background="#D8000000"